# How to export all indicator values by MQL4 programme for all the available MetaTrader Terminal 4 History?

Tags: quantitative-finance, mql4, metatrader4, mql5, metatrader5

Is it possible to export indicator values ( with **`OHLC`** chart data ) from <kbd>MetaTrader Terminal 4</kbd> for all it's available indicator by **`MQL4`** programme?

I've downloaded historical data, loaded into `MT4`, now I want to make `MT4` to calculate all indicators it knows ( or do it from an `MQL4`-code ) and later do some data mining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### How to make this run?

For export, as a trivial unidirectional flow of time does not need to handle individual `QUOTE`-stream events, just design all you wish into an **`MQL4-script`** type of code.

Using a <kbd>**`MetaEditor`**</kbd>, an integrated IDE, you can get all help even from the very first step, by a built in `File->New-[Wizzard]` where you choose to create a **`Script`** type of code and all the needed formal code infrastructure will get setup for you.

You will just add the file-I/O ops and a **`for`**-based loop to visit all bars from your available history, for which you will re-calculate indicator values into the:

```
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Script program start function                                    |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void     OnStart()
{

// _______________________ setup file-IO
   ...

// _______________________ FOR-looper:
   for ( int aBarPTR =  Bars - 1;          // start with the oldest Bar
             aBarPTR <  EMPTY;             //       till the newest Bar
             aBarPTR--                     //       step fwd one-by-one
             )
   {
   // ____________________ calc all values for [aBarPTR]
      ....
   // ____________________ move all values into file-IO
      ...
   }
// _______________________ close file-IO

   return
}
```

And you are done.

### There are two types -- Built-in Indicators and Custom Indicators

The proposed approach works for both of these.

> **`Built-in Indicators`**

Use <kbd>**`MetaEditor`**</kbd> `IDE-Help` to have a list of all built-in Indicator names available in your actual **Build**-version of the <kbd>MetaTrader Terminal 4</kbd> . The scope of implemented indicators may vary.

Enclosed find an excerpt from a custom-syntax highlighting setup, where built-in Indicators were listed separately:

```
# ______________________________________________________________________
# 
# New-MQL4.56789 indicatorFUNCs ________________________Build 950_______

keywordclass.indifunc=\
iAC                                                                     \
iAD                                                                     \
iADX                                                                    \
iAlligator                                                              \
iAO                                                                     \
iATR                                                                    \
iBands                                                                  \
iBandsOnArray                                                           \
iBearsPower                                                             \
iBullsPower                                                             \
iBWMFI                                                                  \
iCCI                                                                    \
iCCIOnArray                                                             \
iCustom                                                                 \
iDeMarker                                                               \
iEnvelopes                                                              \
iEnvelopesOnArray                                                       \
iForce                                                                  \
iFractals                                                               \
iGator                                                                  \
iIchimoku                                                               \
iMA                                                                     \
iMACD                                                                   \
iMAOnArray                                                              \
iMFI                                                                    \
iMomentum                                                               \
iMomentumOnArray                                                        \
iOBV                                                                    \
iOsMA                                                                   \
iRSI                                                                    \
iRSIOnArray                                                             \
iRVI                                                                    \
iSAR                                                                    \
iStdDev                                                                 \
iStdDevOnArray                                                          \
iStochastic                                                             \
iWPR
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

> **`Custom Indicators`**

Use the same `Help` for details on how to setup and query values from any other Custom Indicator of your wish. Just the setup is a bit tedious, but doable, examples in the `Help` will lead you.